# Sql Server Redondear 2 decimales

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola lo que estoy tratando de hacer es redondear un numero a 2 decimales sin contar el tercero, me explico:

Por ejemplo tengo 2.408 y lo que quiero es que salga 2.40.

2.408 -> 2.40
2.418 -> 2.41

Lo que intente:

```
SELECT ROUND(2.408, 2) --2.410
SELECT CAST(2.408 AS DECIMAL(20,2)) --2.41
```

Comment: Entonces no es redondear, estás seleccionando una parte del valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas es truncar y no redondear. Eso lo puedes hacer con el tercer parámetro de `ROUND()`.

```
SELECT ROUND(2.408, 2, 1);
```

Puedes convertir después de truncar para visualizar solo 2 decimales si gustas.

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo en el ejemplo

```
SELECT ROUND(2.408, 2) --2.410
```

tu intención es solo cortar a 2 decimales. por lo que podrías agregar un tercer parámetro al ROUND() sin embargo este traerá desde el tercer decimal en adelante

```
SELECT ROUND(2.408, 2, 1)
```

entonces para solventar el largo del numero, prueba lo siguiente

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(123.456, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(20,2))
SELECT CAST(ROUND(2.408, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(20,2))
```